# mvn versions:set fail after a build failure

Tags: java, maven

My snapshot version looks like 2.7.644-SNAPSHOT
So pom.xml normally look like

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.orderManager</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.644-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>..</relativePath>
</parent>
```

But after a failed release my pom.xml file looks like

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.orderManager</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.644.344</version>
    <relativePath>..</relativePath>
</parent>
```

When I try to correct all versions by running `mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=2.7.644-SNAPSHOT`, I get an error
[image: Fail Message]

mvn is trying to find the failed build jars in a remote repo for some reason.
I'm just trying to change the version names in pom.xml, there's no reason to download jars. Is there a way to run `mvn versions:set` without downloading current version's jars?

Answer (score 0):

Simply before any plugin will be executed on project, Maven need to load your project and resolve needed dependencies.

In case when corrupt your project for any reason, you have options:

- restore previous/correct version of code from scm - if you have
- fix manually problematic versions in poms